# Configurable Color swatch with custom theme in Magento

Tags: magento, configurable

I am trying to use the Configurable color swatch functionality with the custom template, I have copied all the files i.e. catalog.xml,configurableswatches.xml and other template files but I can not see the color icons on the product listing page as well as getting the error on the product description page

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on a non-object in /app/design/frontend/default/testthemes/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml on line 32
```

Anyone please let me know if it is compatible only with the rwd theme or can we use it for the custom templates as well.

Thanks,
Pawan

Answer (score 0):

```
<reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
     <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" before="-" template="catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml">
    <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.options.configurable.renderers" as="attr_renderers" />
    <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.options.configurable.after" as="after" />
    </block>
</reference>
```

Put in `<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable translate="label" module="catalog">` in catalog.xml